# If $D$ is dense in $X$, prove that $\overline {D \cap G}=\overline {G} $ for every open subset $G$ of $X$.

Tags: general-topology

If $D$ is dense in $X$, prove that $\overline {D \cap G}=\overline {G} $ for every open subset $G$ of $X$.

I try this:

If  $D$ is dense then we have that $G\subset D$, more general all open sets are contain in $D$, then using a closure property  $\overline {D \cap G}=\overline {G} \cap \overline{D} $, but   $G\subset D$ then  $\overline{G} \subset\overline{D}$, finally $\overline {D \cap G}=\overline {G} \cap \overline{D} = \overline{G} $

Is it correct? thanks you so much

Comment: As @ericwofsey points out, you attribute far too much to dense sets. They are simply "close" to everything. They need not be open, or even contain any interior at all. They just need to be pesky, or omnipresent, in the sense that no point in the space is far from them.

Comment: $\overline {D \cap G}=\overline {G} \cap \overline{D} $?! what about $Q, Q^c$

Answer (score 6):

Here is a slightly different approach.

We always have $\overline{D \cap G} \subset \overline{G}$ since $D \cap G \subset G$.

Can the reverse containment $\overline{G} \subset \overline{D \cap G}$ fail to hold? Observe that $\overline{G} \subset \overline{D \cap G}$ if and only if $G \subset \overline{D \cap G}$. So if this containment is false, then $G$ has nontrivial intersection with $(\overline{D \cap G})^c$, so $U = G \cap (\overline{D \cap G})^c$ is a nonempty open set which does not intersect with $D \cap G$. Since $U \subset G$, this implies that $U$ does not intersect with $D$. Therefore $D$ must be contained in the closed set $U^c$, so $\overline{D} \subset U^c$. But $D$ is dense in $X$, so $\overline{D} = X$, hence $X = U^c$. This is a contradiction because $U$ is nonempty.

Comment: Nice! Really like this approach.

Answer (score 3):

Dense sets don't *contain* every open set, they just *intersect* every (nonempty) open set.  So you can't say that $G\subset D$; you can only say that $D\cap G$ is nonempty (if $G$ is nonempty and open).

But to prove that $\overline{G}=\overline{D\cap G}$, you aren't going to want to use that property for $G$ itself; rather, you will want to use it for other open sets.  To get you started, suppose you have a point $x\in\overline{G}$.  You want to show that $x\in \overline{D\cap G}$.  So for any open neighborhood $U$ of $x$, you want to show $(D\cap G)\cap U$ is nonempty.  Can you see any way to show this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof by algebra only. We only need to prove $\:{G} \subset \overline{D \cap G}\:$ for $\:\overline{G} \subset \overline{D \cap G}\:$ follows easily.
\begin{align}
G-\overline{D \cap G}\:&=\:G\cap((D \cap G)^c)^o\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\qquad{\overline{A}=((A^c)^o)^c}
\\
&=\:G^o\cap(D^c \cup G^c)^o
\\
&=\:((G\cap D^c) \cup (G\cap G^c))^o\qquad\qquad\qquad{(A\cap B)^o=A^o\cap B^o}
\\
&=\:G\cap (D^c)^o
\\
&=\:G-\overline{D}
\\
&=\:G-X
\\
&=\:\varnothing
\end{align}